# awk duplicated lines with starting with # symbol

Tags: awk

In the below `awk` is there a way to process only lines below a pattern `#CHROM`, however print all in the output. The problem I am having is if I ignore all lines with a `#` they do print in the output, but the other lines without the `#` get duplicated. In my data file there are thousands of lines but only the oone format below is updated by the `awk`. Thank you :).

**file** `tab-delimited`

```
##bcftools_normVersion=1.3.1+htslib-1.3.1
##bcftools_normCommand=norm -m-both -o genome_split.vcf genome.vcf.gz
##bcftools_normCommand=norm -f /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/picard-tools-1.140/resources/ucsc.hg19.fasta -o genome_annovar.vcf genome_split.vcf
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT
chr1    948797  .   C   .   0   PASS    DP=159;END=948845;MAX_DP=224;MIN_DP=95  GT:DP:MIN_DP:MAX_DP 0/0:159:95:224
```

**awk**

```
awk '!/^#/
BEGIN {FS = OFS = "\t"
}
NF == 10 {
split($8, a, /[=;]/)
$11 = $12 = $13 = $14 = $15 = $18 = "."
$16 = (a[1] == "DP") ? a[2] : "DP=num_Missing"
$17 = "homref"
}
1' out > ref
```

**curent output**  `tab-delimited`

```
##bcftools_normVersion=1.3.1+htslib-1.3.1
##bcftools_normCommand=norm -m-both -o genome_split.vcf genome.vcf.gz
##bcftools_normCommand=norm -f /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/picard-tools-1.140/resources/ucsc.hg19.fasta -o genome_annovar.vcf genome_split.vcf
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT
chr1    948797  .   C   .   0   PASS    DP=159;END=948845;MAX_DP=224;MIN_DP=95  GT:DP:MIN_DP:MAX_DP 0/0:159:95:224   --- duplicated line ---
chr1    948797  .   C   .   0   PASS    DP=159;END=948845;MAX_DP=224;MIN_DP=95  GT:DP:MIN_DP:MAX_DP 0/0:159:95:224  .   .   .   .   .   159 homref  .    --- this line is correct ---
```

**desired output** `tab-delimited`

```
##bcftools_normVersion=1.3.1+htslib-1.3.1
##bcftools_normCommand=norm -m-both -o genome_split.vcf genome.vcf.gz
##bcftools_normCommand=norm -f /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/picard-tools-1.140/resources/ucsc.hg19.fasta -o genome_annovar.vcf genome_split.vcf
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT
chr1    948797  .   C   .   0   PASS    DP=159;END=948845;MAX_DP=224;MIN_DP=95  GT:DP:MIN_DP:MAX_DP 0/0:159:95:224  .   .   .   .   .   159 homref  .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first statement:

```
/^#/
```

says "print every line that starts with `#`" and your last:

```
1
```

says "print every line". Hence the duplicate lines in the output.

To only modify lines that don't start with `#` but print all lines would be:

```
!/^#/ { do stuff }
1
```

Comment: So how do I process only lines without `#` but print them in the output? Isn't the `1` needed to update the lines in the file without `#`?  Thank you :).

Comment: That works, but is there a way to process lines after the pattern #CHROM as well? That is only update those lines? Thank you very much :).

Comment: No-one likes [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions). Put it back as it was, accept an answer to the question you asked, and then ask a new question if necessary.

Comment: I was able to figure it out .... thank you very much and will change the post.  Thanks again :).